# Python Data Frame how to find the local maximum in a 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, numpy-ndarray

I have a Data Frame of two columns namely x,y. I want to find the local maximums in x,y plot as shown in figure 1 of attached plot. I followed this way: converted each column of data frame into two separate matrix arrays. Step 1: My code first identifies index positions of local maximums in Y. Step 2: value of x corresponding to the those index positions will be identified. That's it. As a result, i could found two local maximums only. But, there are there three local maximums. My method fail to identify it. My question: is there a way I can identify the local maximum directly from 2D array ?

My present code:

```
x = my_dataframe.iloc[:,0].values # conversion of Data frame column into an array
y = my_dataframe.iloc[:,2].values # conversion of Data frame column into an array        

# Step 1: for local maximum in y list
local_y_index = argrelextrema(y, np.greater)
print("Index position of local maximum in y = ",local_y_index[0])

# Step 2: Below code is for identifying the value of x at local maximum
local_x = x[local_mpp_index[0]]
print("value of x corresponding to local maximum in y = ",local_x)
```

The output is:

```
Index position of local maximum in y =  [105 197]
value of x corresponding to local maximum in y =  [149.21 281.06]
```

My question: As shown in Figure 1, my above approach has identified two local peaks only. But there are three peaks. Is there a better approach to identify the local maximum directly from 2D array of x and y?

[image]

```
x = [1.0330e-01, 1.0380e-01, 1.0430e-01, 1.0680e-01, 1.1932e-01, 1.8192e-01,
 3.6365e-01, 5.4539e-01, 7.9191e-01, 1.0384e+00, 1.3626e+00, 1.6869e+00,
 1.7438e+00, 2.0286e+00, 2.4825e+00, 2.9363e+00, 3.4787e+00, 4.0212e+00,
 4.7129e+00, 5.2137e+00, 6.0460e+00, 6.9486e+00, 7.8511e+00, 8.6835e+00,
 1.0092e+01, 1.0418e+01, 1.2153e+01, 1.3888e+01, 1.5623e+01, 1.7358e+01,
 1.9093e+01, 2.0828e+01, 2.2563e+01, 2.4298e+01, 2.6033e+01, 2.7768e+01,
 2.9503e+01, 3.1237e+01, 3.2972e+01, 3.4707e+01, 3.6442e+01, 3.8177e+01,
 3.9912e+01, 4.1647e+01, 4.3382e+01, 4.5117e+01, 4.6852e+01, 4.8587e+01,
 5.0322e+01, 5.2056e+01, 5.3791e+01, 5.5526e+01, 5.7261e+01, 5.8996e+01,
 6.0731e+01, 6.2466e+01, 6.4201e+01, 6.5936e+01, 6.7671e+01, 6.9406e+01,
 7.1141e+01, 7.2875e+01, 7.4610e+01, 7.6345e+01, 7.8080e+01, 7.9815e+01,
 8.1550e+01, 8.3285e+01, 8.5020e+01, 8.6755e+01, 8.8490e+01, 9.0225e+01,
 9.1960e+01, 9.3694e+01, 9.5429e+01, 9.7164e+01, 9.8899e+01, 1.0063e+02,
 1.0237e+02, 1.0410e+02, 1.0584e+02, 1.0757e+02, 1.0931e+02, 1.1104e+02,
 1.1278e+02, 1.1451e+02, 1.1625e+02, 1.1798e+02, 1.1972e+02, 1.2145e+02,
 1.2319e+02, 1.2492e+02, 1.2666e+02, 1.2839e+02, 1.3013e+02, 1.3186e+02,
 1.3360e+02, 1.3533e+02, 1.3707e+02, 1.3880e+02, 1.4054e+02, 1.4227e+02,
 1.4401e+02, 1.4574e+02, 1.4748e+02, 1.4921e+02, 1.5095e+02, 1.5268e+02,
 1.5442e+02, 1.5615e+02, 1.5684e+02, 1.5753e+02, 1.5789e+02, 1.5861e+02,
 1.5934e+02, 1.5962e+02, 1.6056e+02, 1.6136e+02, 1.6256e+02, 1.6309e+02,
 1.6482e+02, 1.6656e+02, 1.6829e+02, 1.7003e+02, 1.7176e+02, 1.7350e+02,
 1.7523e+02, 1.7697e+02, 1.7870e+02, 1.8044e+02, 1.8217e+02, 1.8391e+02,
 1.8564e+02, 1.8738e+02, 1.8911e+02, 1.9085e+02, 1.9258e+02, 1.9432e+02,
 1.9605e+02, 1.9779e+02, 1.9952e+02, 2.0126e+02, 2.0299e+02, 2.0473e+02,
 2.0646e+02, 2.0820e+02, 2.0993e+02, 2.1167e+02, 2.1340e+02, 2.1514e+02,
 2.1687e+02, 2.1861e+02, 2.1927e+02, 2.1993e+02, 2.2034e+02, 2.2103e+02,
 2.2172e+02, 2.2208e+02, 2.2296e+02, 2.2381e+02, 2.2493e+02, 2.2555e+02,
 2.2700e+02, 2.2728e+02, 2.2871e+02, 2.2902e+02, 2.3057e+02, 2.3075e+02,
 2.3164e+02, 2.3249e+02, 2.3422e+02, 2.3596e+02, 2.3769e+02, 2.3943e+02,
 2.4116e+02, 2.4290e+02, 2.4463e+02, 2.4637e+02, 2.4810e+02, 2.4984e+02,
 2.5157e+02, 2.5331e+02, 2.5504e+02, 2.5678e+02, 2.5851e+02, 2.6025e+02,
 2.6198e+02, 2.6371e+02, 2.6545e+02, 2.6718e+02, 2.6892e+02, 2.7065e+02,
 2.7239e+02, 2.7412e+02, 2.7586e+02, 2.7759e+02, 2.7933e+02, 2.8106e+02,
 2.8280e+02, 2.8453e+02, 2.8627e+02, 2.8800e+02, 2.8974e+02, 2.9147e+02,
 2.9321e+02, 2.9494e+02, 2.9668e+02, 2.9841e+02, 3.0015e+02, 3.0188e+02,
 3.0362e+02, 3.0535e+02, 3.0709e+02, 3.0882e+02, 3.1056e+02, 3.1229e+02,
 3.1403e+02, 3.1576e+02, 3.1749e+02, 3.1923e+02, 3.2096e+02, 3.2270e+02,
 3.2443e+02, 3.2617e+02, 3.2790e+02, 3.2964e+02, 3.3137e+02, 3.3311e+02,
 3.3484e+02, 3.3658e+02, 3.4686e+02, 3.4686e+02, 3.4686e+02, 3.4686e+02,
 3.4686e+02, 3.4686e+02, 3.4686e+02, 3.4686e+02, 3.4687e+02]

y = [4.2014e-01, 4.2237e-01, 4.2460e-01, 4.3574e-01, 4.9146e-01, 7.7004e-01,
     1.5788e+00, 2.3874e+00, 3.4842e+00, 4.5808e+00, 6.0228e+00, 7.4647e+00,
     7.7180e+00, 8.9843e+00, 1.1002e+01, 1.3020e+01, 1.5431e+01, 1.7842e+01,
     2.0916e+01, 2.3141e+01, 2.6839e+01, 3.0848e+01, 3.4856e+01, 3.8552e+01,
     4.4807e+01, 4.6254e+01, 5.3953e+01, 6.1650e+01, 6.9344e+01, 7.7035e+01,
     8.4723e+01, 9.2409e+01, 1.0009e+02, 1.0777e+02, 1.1545e+02, 1.2312e+02,
     1.3079e+02, 1.3846e+02, 1.4613e+02, 1.5379e+02, 1.6145e+02, 1.6911e+02,
     1.7677e+02, 1.8442e+02, 1.9207e+02, 1.9971e+02, 2.0735e+02, 2.1499e+02,
     2.2263e+02, 2.3027e+02, 2.3790e+02, 2.4552e+02, 2.5315e+02, 2.6077e+02,
     2.6839e+02, 2.7600e+02, 2.8361e+02, 2.9122e+02, 2.9882e+02, 3.0642e+02,
     3.1401e+02, 3.2160e+02, 3.2918e+02, 3.3676e+02, 3.4433e+02, 3.5190e+02,
     3.5946e+02, 3.6701e+02, 3.7455e+02, 3.8209e+02, 3.8961e+02, 3.9712e+02,
     4.0462e+02, 4.1211e+02, 4.1958e+02, 4.2703e+02, 4.3447e+02, 4.4188e+02,
     4.4926e+02, 4.5661e+02, 4.6393e+02, 4.7122e+02, 4.7846e+02, 4.8565e+02,
     4.9278e+02, 4.9985e+02, 5.0685e+02, 5.1376e+02, 5.2057e+02, 5.2728e+02,
     5.3386e+02, 5.4029e+02, 5.4656e+02, 5.5265e+02, 5.5852e+02, 5.6415e+02,
     5.6950e+02, 5.7453e+02, 5.7920e+02, 5.8347e+02, 5.8727e+02, 5.9056e+02,
     5.9325e+02, 5.9527e+02, 5.9654e+02, 5.9697e+02, 5.9646e+02, 5.9490e+02,
     5.9217e+02, 5.9175e+02, 5.9419e+02, 5.9665e+02, 5.9790e+02, 6.0049e+02,
     6.0309e+02, 6.0410e+02, 6.0748e+02, 6.1034e+02, 6.1467e+02, 6.1658e+02,
     6.2282e+02, 6.2905e+02, 6.3528e+02, 6.4151e+02, 6.4772e+02, 6.5393e+02,
     6.6013e+02, 6.6632e+02, 6.7251e+02, 6.7868e+02, 6.8484e+02, 6.9099e+02,
     6.9712e+02, 7.0323e+02, 7.0931e+02, 7.1536e+02, 7.2137e+02, 7.2732e+02,
     7.3320e+02, 7.3899e+02, 7.4464e+02, 7.5013e+02, 7.5540e+02, 7.6039e+02,
     7.6502e+02, 7.6922e+02, 7.7287e+02, 7.7589e+02, 7.7817e+02, 7.7962e+02,
     7.8014e+02, 7.8039e+02, 7.8250e+02, 7.8464e+02, 7.8598e+02, 7.8823e+02,
     7.9050e+02, 7.9166e+02, 7.9458e+02, 7.9739e+02, 8.0109e+02, 8.0313e+02,
     8.0793e+02, 8.0888e+02, 8.1359e+02, 8.1462e+02, 8.1978e+02, 8.2036e+02,
     8.2330e+02, 8.2610e+02, 8.3183e+02, 8.3755e+02, 8.4326e+02, 8.4897e+02,
     8.5466e+02, 8.6035e+02, 8.6602e+02, 8.7168e+02, 8.7732e+02, 8.8295e+02,
     8.8855e+02, 8.9412e+02, 8.9965e+02, 9.0513e+02, 9.1055e+02, 9.1588e+02,
     9.2110e+02, 9.2618e+02, 9.3108e+02, 9.3576e+02, 9.4015e+02, 9.4420e+02,
     9.4784e+02, 9.5100e+02, 9.5362e+02, 9.5563e+02, 9.5698e+02, 9.5761e+02,
     9.5746e+02, 9.5650e+02, 9.5468e+02, 9.5195e+02, 9.4828e+02, 9.4363e+02,
     9.3796e+02, 9.3122e+02, 9.2337e+02, 9.1437e+02, 9.0418e+02, 8.9275e+02,
     8.8004e+02, 8.6600e+02, 8.5059e+02, 8.3376e+02, 8.1546e+02, 7.9566e+02,
     7.7430e+02, 7.5134e+02, 7.2674e+02, 7.0046e+02, 6.7244e+02, 6.4266e+02,
     6.1108e+02, 5.7765e+02, 5.4234e+02, 5.0512e+02, 4.6596e+02, 4.2483e+02,
     3.8170e+02, 3.3654e+02, 6.8800e-05, 5.1500e-05, 4.8000e-05, 4.7300e-05,
     4.7200e-05, 4.7200e-05, 4.7200e-05, 4.7200e-05, 1.5520e-04]
```

Comment: Could you also post the data (or a way to generate similar data)? Furthermore, it might help if we have the body of your `argrelextrema` method.

Comment: I am new to python and this stackoverlfow. Could you help me, how to upload data? So that I can upload it here.

Comment: If you have a CSV of the data (or any other reasonable data file), you could post it to e.g. [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and share the link with us here. If you can provide us with a way to generate the data instead, that is fine as well (e.g. some random data).

Comment: Yes, please, now I have modified my question and included the x and y values.

Comment: I see - this is fine! Thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into my question. Please, copy the data before someone starts flagging my questions as negative saying it is lengthy or some other reason.

Comment: It is easy to see how to get the two maxima at 105 and 197, as you don't even need the `x` data for that.  But how do you define the condition such that you expect a maximum to be found in that middle area?  Is it any place where the slope begins to decrease?

Comment: Are you sure there is some `maxima` there? Checking the data, I did find no maxima between indices 106 and 97!

Comment: @John Zwinck. Correct. From Fig. 2 it is clear that first and last maximum can be found. Here, x is not required to identify the local maximum. In Fig. 2 (which is drawn between index of y and y), middle peak is not properly visible. But, if you see the Fig. 1 (which is drawn between x and y) visibility of the middle peak is much better. I am hoping, if we could include search arrays at a time, it is possible to find all local maximums. Any inputs please?

Comment: Search if there is any point which is smaller than it's previous point: `[y[i] for i in range(1,len(y[106:197])) if y[i]<y[i-1]]`, between those two maximas (There is no).

Comment: @ Alla Tarighati. I got this data from my simulation tests. In which, I have applied three different conditions. It looks like that the third peak (middle one) is neither not clear nor satisfying the standard local maximum definition. I want the python to identify it. Assume, there is no maximum. But, presence of a small notch which I circled in Fig. 1 indicates the presence of peak.

Comment: @Msquare There are definitely no local maxima or peaks inside that crircle and it is not clear what you mean by "small notch".

Answer (score 1):

Any extremum is such that the derivative at the extremum is zero. As we do not have an analytic expression for the data, the next best thing we can do is approximate the derivative. This is essentially the same as taking the 1-step difference and looking for those values that are 'small'.

The following works well for me,

```
def find_extrema(frame, tolerance=0.5):
    diff = frame.diff()

    extrema = diff[np.abs(diff) < tolerance]

    return extrema[~np.isnan(extrema.y)]


df = pd.DataFrame(dict(y=y), index=x)

candidates = find_extrema(df)

print(candidates)
```

And I find,

```
                      y
0.10380    2.230000e-03
0.10430    2.230000e-03
0.10680    1.114000e-02
0.11932    5.572000e-02
0.18192    2.785800e-01
1.74380    2.533000e-01
149.21000  4.300000e-01
156.15000 -4.200000e-01
218.61000  2.500000e-01
282.80000 -1.500000e-01
346.86000 -1.730000e-05
346.86000 -3.500000e-06
346.86000 -7.000000e-07
346.86000 -1.000000e-07
346.86000  0.000000e+00
346.86000  0.000000e+00
346.86000  0.000000e+00
346.87000  1.080000e-04
```

This will require some cleaning still (mostly on the edges), but the general idea should hopefully be clear to you.

The following plot was made with,

```
tolerance = 0.75

diff = df.diff()

ax = diff[np.abs(diff) < tolerance].y.plot(
     title="Derivative approximation for tolerance = {0}".format(tolerance))

ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y[x] - y[x - 1]")

plt.show()
```

(notice the larger tolerance, so we can actually observe some lines rather than just points)

[image: Extrema]

Comment: Notice of course that, as your function is not concave, you should check if the points next to the extremum are smaller! Else you may stumble into inflection points, minima, and all sorts of otherwise unrelated fun.

Comment: Looks like i have some serious lessons to learn here as I am still trying to understand what is going on here. I agree! derivative at maximum=0. Here, you are identifying the difference 'dy' for a 'dx'. If I understood correctly, your code is  trying to calculate dy for given dx=0.5 and then dy/dx. Am I right?

Comment: It takes the difference with the previous element in `y` (previous row), which does not respect the `x`-axis. You could include that also, but then the approach becomes a bit more elaborate. But yes, fundamentally, I do try to approximate `dy/dx` and find those places where it is 'small' (less than some tolerance).

Comment: Could you please explain how did you got above plot (which parameters)? What is its significance and it is trying to tell? I am happy to see this plot because, it shows lines corresponding to the peak locations. More importantly, at middle peak which I failed to identify in first go?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `np.gradient` function and look where the gradient changes sign:

```
z = np.gradient(y, x)
i = 0
while i < len(x)-2:
if (z[i]*z[i+2]<=0 and z[i]>0): #gradient changes sign > optima, and point previous to optima has a positive slope
        print(i+1, x[i+1], y[i+1])
        i = i+1
    i+=1

plt.ylim(-1, 1)
plt.plot(x, z)
```

Looing at the plot, it seems the point at around 210 is not a maxima (the gradient doesnt reach zero). You can check this by replacing the `if` statement with the following `if (y[i+1]>y[i] and y[i+1]>y[i+2]):`

Answer (score 1):

Here comes my naive approach:

**Step 1:** find a list containing slopes, which is `+1` if two consecutive`y`-values are increasing, `-1` if decreasing and `0` if are the same:

```
import numpy as np
slope = [np.sign(y[i]-y[i-1]) for i in range(1, len(y))]
```

Now if you print `slope`, it's gonna be just either `0,1,-1` which says about slopes between each two consecutive `y` points.

**Step2:** To find `minimas` and `maximas`, I wrote this code which evaluates if the slope changes or not. If it changes from `1` to `-1` the index will be saved as a `maxima`, otherwise as `minima`.

```
x_prev = slope[0]
optima_dic={'minima':[], 'maxima':[]}
for i in range(1, len(slope)):
    if slope[i]*x_prev==-1: #slope changed
        if x_prev==1: # slope changed from 1 to -1
            optima_dic['maxima'].append(i)
        else: # slope changed from -1 to 1
            optima_dic['minima'].append(i)
        x_prev=-x_prev
```

and if you print the results:

```
print(optima_dic)
```

Output:

```
{'minima': [109, 237], 'maxima': [105, 197]}
```

Quick and dirty :)